# Xcode > Source Control > Create Git Repositories

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, macos-mojave

I use Xcode 10 Mac OS X Mojave. I went to

Source Control > Create Git Repositories to create my initial commit

[image]

It seems success. but I'm not sure where my Xcode push my code to？

In my Xcode I went to sourcecode I see this

[image]

In my Bitbucket account, I see nothing pushed or created.
Bitbucket is the only account I linked in my **Xcode** > **preferences**.

I ran `git config --list`, I got

```
⚡️  Alimofire  git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=john doe
user.email=john@outlook.com
core.excludesfile=/Users/bheng/.gitignore_global
core.filemode=false
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
push.default=matching
commit.template=/Users/bheng/.stCommitMsg
core.bare=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

Where is my code now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chose Source Control > Create Git Repositories, you created a local git repository on your Mac. That command doesn't create a Bitbucket repository or push changes to Bitbucket.

Use Xcode's source control navigator to put your project on Bitbucket. Open the Source Control navigator by choosing View > Navigators > Show Source Control Navigator. Select the Remotes folder, control-click, and choose Create Remote to create a remote repository on Bitbucket.

Avoid having uppercase letters in the repository name. If there are uppercase letters in the repository name, Xcode opens an alert saying **An unknown error occurred**. This is an issue for Bitbucket repositories, not GitHub repositories.

Choose Source Control > Push to push your changes to Bitbucket. You can find more detailed information in the following article:

[Putting Your Xcode Project on GitHub, Bitbucket, or GitLab](https://swiftdevjournal.com/putting-your-xcode-project-on-github-bitbucket-or-gitlab/)